# Cant put Query inside Create sequence sql

Tags: oracle

The Below query is failing. How to correct it I need to put max id from `TBL_PLANNING_REPOSITORY` in the create sequence start with.

```
CREATE sequence auto_id_planning_repo 
start with (select MAX(ID) from TBL_PLANNING_REPOSITORY) increment by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE
   v_startwith   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX (ID) INTO v_startwith FROM TBL_PLANNING_REPOSITORY;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'create sequence auto_id_planning_repo  start with ' || v_startwith || ' increment by 1';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

DDL statements cannot be mixed with DML expressions. Correct way is something like this:

```
lock table tbl_planning_repository in exclusive mode;
var m number;
exec select max(id) into :m from tbl_planning_repository;
exec execute immediate 'create sequence ... start with ' || :m || ' increment by 1';
```